# Get attachments list in CouchDB using Mustaches.js

Tags: javascript, html, templates, couchdb, mustache

How to get list of attachments in CouchDB, using Mustaches.js

JSON example:

```
{
   "_id": "t",
   "_rev": "9-5eed240a008b0eb6efbaf9a439c43279",
   "_attachments": {
       "Doc1.pdf": {
           "content_type": "application/pdf",
           "revpos": 8,
           "digest": "md5-pxnGZT6uqX4n2+vNNIOs/g==",
           "length": 200633,
           "stub": true
       },
       "Doc2.pdf": {
           "content_type": "application/pdf",
           "revpos": 6,
           "digest": "md5-fxnGZT6uqX2n2+vNNI41s/g==",
           "length": 100333,
           "stub": true
       }
   }
}
```

My template looks like this:

```
{{^isAttEmpty}}
  <p>Lista załączników:<p>
   <ul>
    {{#_attachments}}
     <li>{{@key}} - URL:{{This will be URL to Image}}</li>
    {{/_attachments}}
   </ul>
 {{/isAttEmpty}}
```

Did Mustache.js have build in function to iterate objects ? Or should I parsing to array before send to Mustaches ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Mustache.js can iterate only over array members, not object keys.

In your `show` function you will have to format the object you will send to Mustache accordingly.
Here is a function you could use to transform attachments into an array:

```js
function formatAttachments(attachments, docID) {
  var result = [];
  for (a in attachments) {
    result.push({
      name: a,
      size: Math.round(attachments[a].length/104857.6)/10,
      url: docID + "/" + a
    });
  }
  return result;
}
```